# creating many triangles with different points

Tags: java, geometry

I have a question that in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle)

you will see `pointInTriangle` Method with 4 parameters .I want to know that how can I send those 3 last parameters to this method when we have n points? Is there any way to do this at O(n^3)

please help me thanks

Comment: A triangle does not have more than three (3) points. Do you want a function that checks if a point is **within** a _Polygon_ in O(n^3)?

Comment: @dacwe I assume he means checking whether n points are inside a triangle, rather than checking whether one point is inside a n-side polygon.

Comment: But looking at his link the last three parameters are the triangle points..

Comment: @dacwe: Yes, the question is not completely clear. However since both the title and the tags mention "triangles", I believe he means checking n points against a triangle, instead of one point against a polygon -- but of course I could be wrong.

Comment: @user472221: Perhaps you should clarify the question instead of us trying to find out what you actually meant :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use [`Polygon.contains(Point)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) instead?

Comment: Polygon does it in O(n), that's way better! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear, but assuming you just want to extend [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle/2049593#2049593) to check for n points, I guess you can do something like this:

```
private static float sign(fPoint p1, fPoint p2, fPoint p3)
{
    return (p1.x - p3.x) * (p2.y - p3.y) - (p2.x - p3.x) * (p1.y - p3.y);
}

public static boolean[] pointsInTriangle(fPoint[] pt, fPoint v1, fPoint v2, fPoint v3)
{
    boolean b1, b2, b3;

    boolean[] ret = new boolean[pt.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pt.length; i++)
    {
        b1 = sign(pt[i], v1, v2) < 0.0f;
        b2 = sign(pt[i], v2, v3) < 0.0f;
        b3 = sign(pt[i], v3, v1) < 0.0f;
        ret[i] = ((b1 == b2) && (b2 == b3)); 
    }
    return ret;
}
```

By the way, this is O(n).