# 2D Point in triangle test implemented on Android

Tags: android, geometry, 2d, point, intersection

I want to determine if a **2D point** is *inside* a **triangle** using pure java on the **Android** platform. I reserve a special bonus for using the same representation for 2D points that is used in Android for drawing triangles ([Canvas.drawVertices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawVertices%28android.graphics.Canvas.VertexMode,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20short%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)).

I have already found [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle) for the intersection test itself, but they are not adapted to Android the way I would like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grew (very) impatient and implemented this myself, based on the answer linked to in the question I now have two ways of testing. TODO: reduce temporary allocation.

```
import android.graphics.PointF;
//...
private float sign(PointF p1, PointF p2, PointF p3) {
    return (p1.x - p3.x) * (p2.y - p3.y) - (p2.x - p3.x) * (p1.y - p3.y);
}

private boolean pointInTriangle(PointF pt, PointF v1, PointF v2, PointF v3) {
    boolean b1, b2, b3;
    b1 = sign(pt, v1, v2) < 0.0f;
    b2 = sign(pt, v2, v3) < 0.0f;
    b3 = sign(pt, v3, v1) < 0.0f;
    return ((b1 == b2) && (b2 == b3));
}

private boolean pointInTriangle(float x, float y, float[] v) {
    return pointInTriangle(new PointF(x, y), new PointF(v[0], v[1]), new PointF(v[2], v[3]), new PointF(v[4], v[5]));
}
```

Comment: I don't need to worry about performance so it's perfect for my needs. I used this algorithm in Javascript by the way.