# How to determine a point in a triangle with THIS special method (see link)?

Tags: javascript, geometry, triangulation

I am trying to get a working algorytm to check if a point is within a triangle.

I found this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21510010/2429323

and i understand the first part of explanation. But i don't understand the rest. What does he mean with Xi Yj and Yk. Can Someone  follow his thoughts and help me?

I would ask him personally, but it seems there is no PM possible, and i can't write a comment to (Reputation).

Comment: Why didn't you take any of the other fine answers?

Comment: The performance seems to be not that good - i need to do this calculation not only once.

Comment: Seems to be? Did you actually test it?

Comment: Not yet, he says his way is much more efficient, why should i try other (slower) ways if i know there is a faster one. Doesn't make much sense for me. Of course it's a fallback, if i can't figure it out. Edit: Maybe you can put an comment below his answer and link my question (so he could react if he recognize it)

Comment: It just applies early rejection if the point falls outside of the bounding box; the other comparisons still need to take place.