# glsl fragment shader calculate texture position

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm writing a fragment shader for rendering a 1D texture containing an arbitrary byte array into a kind of barcode.
my idea is to encode each byte into a square divided diagonally (so each of the 4 triangles represents 2 bit), like so:

```
 _____
|\ A /|  each byte encoded as binary is DDCCBBAA,
| \ / |  the colors are: Red   if 11
|D X B|                  Green if 10
| / \ |                  Blue  if 01
|/ C \|                  Black if 00
 ¯¯¯¯¯   so color can be calculated as: [(H & L), (H & !L), (!H & L)]

so for example: 198 == 11 00 01 10 would be:
 _____                 DD CC BB AA
|\ G /| 
| \ / | A=10=Green
|R X B| B=01=Blue
| / \ | C=00=Black
|/ b \| D=11=Red
 ¯¯¯¯¯  (B=Blue, b=Black)
```

what I got so far are a function for encoding 2 bools (H,L in the example notation) into a vec3 color and a function for encoding a byte and "corner index" (A/B/C/D in the example) into the color:

```
#version 400
out vec4 gl_FragColor; // the output fragment
in vec2 vf_texcoord; // normalized texture coords, 0/0=top/left
uniform isampler1D uf_texture; // the input data
uniform int uf_texLen; // the input data's byte count
vec3 encodeColor(bool H, bool L){
  return vec3(H&&L,H&&!L,!H&&L);
}
vec3 encodeByte(int data,int corner){
  int maskL = 1 << corner;
  int maskH = maskL << 1;
  int shiftL = corner/2;
  int shiftH = shiftL+1;
  bool H=bool((data&maskH)>>shiftH);
  bool L=bool((data&maskL)>>shiftL);
  return encodeColor(H,L);
}
void main(void) {

  // the part I can't figure out

  gl_FragColor.rgb=encodeByte(/* some stuff calculated by the part above*/);
  gl_FragColor.a=1;
}
```

the problem is I can't figure out how to calculate which byte to encode and in what "corner" the current fragment is.

Comment: "Each of the 4 triangles represents 2 *bytes?*"  Did you mean bits?

Comment: Assuming you are actually drawing all of the geometry, why not specify two uniform values per triangle with the "byte to encode" and "corner"?

Comment: If this colored square represents one byte, but your raw data consists of multiple bytes, you'll need to display multiple squares somehow, and it's not clear how you intend to do that.  Are you drawing each square as a separate GL primitive (e.g. triangle fan), or are you drawing a single rectangle with GL and relying on the fragment shader to display different colored squares within it?

Comment: @RogerAllen because the two "triangles" i mention aren't geometry `GL_TRIANGLES`, but the whole thing is rendered as one big rectangle (as a VBO of 2 tris). the triangles I mention in the question are just the upper/lower/left/right quarter of each byte representing square.

Comment: @Wyzard I render the whole string as one big rectangle, so calculating which byte of the string to handle for each fragment is up to the fragment shader.

Comment: so what I'm basically doing here is a color coded 2d barcode :D

Comment: Then you need to provide more detail about how you want the shaded squares to be arranged within that single piece of geometry.  If I want to display 7 bytes, should the 7 squares be arranged horizontally?  Vertically?  In a grid?  what determines the number of rows/cols in the grid?

Comment: Sure would be way simpler if you used geometry.  You'll need to use the frag x,y inputs and something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle

Comment: @Wyzard: in the first step I think arranging them horizontally would suffice (so I see that it works at least), but in the future I'd like it to be "as square as possible with the lower right squares black", so your 7 bytes would be arranged as: `1st line=(0,1,2), 2nd=(3,4,5),3rd=(6,black,black)`

Comment: @RogerAllen yes, it'll be simpler, but I'd like to do as much as possible inside the shader, because I'll be using this in a performance heavy app, trying to eliminate VRAM throughput and draw calls. I use this "unit square VBO" primitive for font rendering too, and I hope being able to use this for almost all GUI elements, so it'd be nice to do the whole "barcode drawing" as a matter of "bind gui square VBO, bind barcode shader, set data texture, DrawElements()"

Comment: Consider using a geometry shader to generate the triangles dynamically in the GPU.  Each one can just be a solid color (chosen by the geometry shader), so the fragment shader is trivial.

Comment: @Wyzard but then I would just move the problem towards the geometry shader. I think I have all required variables anyway (normalized coords of the current fragment inside the output quad, and size of the sampler1D), the only problem is I don't know how to calculate the required values.

Comment: But the work done by the geometry shader is proportional to the number of triangles you're generating, instead of the number of pixels in the final image.  Since each triangle probably covers more than one pixel (and certainly shouldn't cover less, or your barcode is unreadable), this may mean less overall work for the GPU.  (I'm not sure about relative performance of geometry vs. fragment shaders, though.)

Comment: @Wyzard I agree that could be a nice optimization, but I'm afraid I also don't know the formulas for that situation. but of course if you could point me to the correct calculations for that, I'll be happy to use them :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Note, the code here is is off the top of my head and untested, and I haven't written a lot of GLSL.  The variable names are sloppy and I've probably made some stupid syntax mistakes, but it should be enough to convey the idea.)*

The first thing you need to do is translate the texture coordinates into a data index (which square to display colors for) and a modified set of texture coordinates that represent the position *within* that square.

For a horizontal arrangement, you could do something like:

```
float temp = vf_texcoord.x * uf_texLen;
float temp2 = floor(temp);
int dataIndex = temp2;
vec2 squareTexcoord = { temp2 - temp, vf_texcoord.y };
```

Then you'd use `squareTexcoord` to decide which quadrant of the square you're in:

```
int corner;
vec2 squareTexcoord2 = squareTexcoord - { 0.5, 0.5 }
if (abs(squareTexcoord2.x) > abs(squareTexcoord2.y)) {  // Left or right triangle
    if (squareTexcoord2.x > 0) {  // Right triangle
        corner = 0;
    }
    else {  // Left triangle
        corner = 1;
    }
}
else {  // Top or bottom triangle
    if (squareTexcoord2.y > 0) {  // Bottom triangle
        corner = 2;
    }
    else {  // Top triangle
        corner = 3;
    }
}
```

And now you have all you need for shading:

```
gl_FragColor = { encodeByte(int(texelFetch(uf_texture,dataIndex,0).r), corner), 1.0 };
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the `abs(squareTexcoord2.x) > abs(squareTexcoord2.y)` line. as far as I see that would check if we're in the lower right half of the sqare?

Comment: It's checking whether the point is more to the left or right than it is to the top or bottom, which tells you whether it's in the "bow tie" or the "hourglass" part of the square.

Comment: btw, when using this code with a data texture of length=1, and only byte being 13, i get a 100% black output.

Comment: ah, yes, sure, seems like my brain kinda ignored the `abs` call when parsing that line :D

Comment: It's probably buggy; I haven't written any real GLSL in a year or so.  Read it for the general idea, not the exact implementation.

Comment: yeah, i fixed some casting issues your code had, but as I'm catching all GLSL compiler errors, the only possible bug would be runtime.

Comment: If you're testing with a single byte of data, take out the first part and just set `squareTexcoord = vf_texcoord` to eliminate one possible source of bugs.

Comment: did that, but still black. according to my manual calculations, 13 (=1101b) would be a square with upper triangle red and right triangle blue.

Comment: I'd use a value where all the triangles should be non-black in order to make it obvious whether you're drawing anything at all.  But SO comments aren't really a place for interactive debugging help; there's not much I can do for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57735/discussion-between-nonchip-and-wyzard).