# Code for telling if coordinate is outside, inside or on the border of shape

Tags: if-statement, coordinates, pascal, freepascal

User types value of x and y which will be a coordinate. There is some kind of a shape there and I need to tell if that coordinate will be outside, inside or on the border of that shape.
I know how to do that with rectangle shape, but not with triangle or circle.
Currently I need to do this with this shape: http://i.imgur.com/5teZk85.png

How do I do this for circle or triangle shape?

For rectangle I used these code lines:

```
IF (x>=-5) AND (x<=2) AND (y>=-1) AND (y<=3) then
   IF (x=-5) OR (x=2) OR (y=-1) OR (y=3) then
      writeln('Dot is located on line')
   else writeln('Dot is located inside')
   else writeln('Dot is located outside');
```

Comment: To get answer from SO, you would need to provide some more details on how do you model the problem in your program using your chosen programming language.

Comment: It's a wide topic. check this pdf: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos226/lectures/geosearch.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a circle, you can do the following test:

If `x^2 + y^2 < r^2`, then it is inside the circle.

For triangles, you should probably look at this question:
[How to determine if a point is in a 2D triangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle)

Comment: And how can i tell if it's going to be on the border of circle and not inside/outside?

Comment: If it is on the border of the circle, `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`, and if it is outside, then `x^2 + y^2 > r^2`.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I enrolled for an online course about algorithms, held by Robert Sedgewick. One topic was "Geometric Search", it describes you problem. Therefore I don't want to post a code snippet here, but suggest to read one of his books. See my comment for a pdf that might help you to get on the right track.

Comment: A link to an external site that provides the solution is not considered an answer here. You should either provide an answer here  post the link as a comment to the original question instead.