# Algorithm to join 4 co-ordinates such that it always results in a quadilateral

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, coordinate-systems, coordinate

We're given the coordinates of 4 points on the 2D plane. How can we find an order to join them with lines to form a [quadilateral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) (whenever it's possible)?

Comment: What if the points are collinear?

Comment: Need to draw a straight line in that case.

Comment: There's only 3 possibilities: ABCD, ABDC, ACBD. Try them all?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A few stages, assuming the end result needs to be 4 couples of points (and/or the equation of the line between them):

1. Take any three points, and make a triangle.
2. If the forth point is inside the traingle, swap it with ny of the three.
3. Having only the last point left, calculate which two point you want to attach it to. This is done by  playing with the line eqations and finding where the intersecting points are. Clarification below.
4. Return two sides of the triangle + the 2 lines between the forth point and the ones you chose from stage 2.

Step 2 clarification:
Let us say that point A is not in the triangle (which is BCD). Every line devides the plain into two sides. we want to find the point (B, C or D) s.t. the line between it and A runs between the other two (they are on opposite sides of the line). This is the point we DO NOT want to attach to A.

Example:
Given A(0,0), B(10,0), C(10,10) and D(0,10). We have the triangle BCD. The line BC leaves A & D on the same side of the plain. So does DC. The line AC leaves B & D on opposite sides of the plain - so we want to connect A to B & C.

Comment: if already a triangle is made, how can quadilateral be made with last point

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes. Step 2 is a bit vague, but otherwise this is the only correct answer.

Comment: Down voted ,exactly for that reason. Step 2 could be written better

Comment: @CarbineCoder, Please see clarification.

Comment: If this is a concave structure. There wont be any intersecting points between the diagonals. Points A(0,0), B(5,5),C(10,0), D(5,10). I don't think this logic will work. Or in simple words - What if the 4th point lies within the triangle?

Comment: @CarbineCoder, I actually didn't think of that. If this is the case, chose the inside point as one of the initial three and re-run the algorithm.

Comment: Nice :) How will you know that you have an inside point? That logic should also be included into the algorithm.

Comment: @CarbineCoder, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle) is an answer to that.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the partition of the plane obtained by drawing the three lines defined by the first three points. It defines 7 regions. You can easily find to which region the fourth point belongs by means of three signed area tests (algebraic area of the triangles ABD, BCD, CAD).

Drawing a quadrilateral in every case is straightforward (there can be one, two or three solutions per case).

In the example below, with D in the region `-++`, ADBC will do.

[image]

Actually two area evaluations are enough: if the first test returns `-` (regions `-+-`, `-++` or `--+`), ADBC is a solution, else if the second test returns `-` (regions `+-+` or `+--`), ABDC is a solution, else (regions `++-` or `+++`) ABCD is a solution .

Comment: How did you derive that signed area test in terms of 3 terms like `-++`? What does -++ dignify here! Please explain.

Comment: @shekharsuman: algebraic area of the triangles ABD, BCD, CAD. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_coordinates

Comment: @shekharsuman: I don't thank you for the downvote. This is an optimal solution, extremely simple to implement. Two area evaluations, and two tests !

Comment: @shekharsuman: you missed the whole thing. The collinearity test is the same expression as the signed area. This is the standard too in computational geometry. You perform it four times instead of two and drop the important information, which is the sign. This forces you to post-process by sorting (which you don't clearly detail).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the affine transform

```
Px = Ax + u (Bx - Ax) + v (Cx - Ax)
Py = Ay + u (By - Ay) + v (Cy - Ay)
```

It maps `(0, 0)` to `A`, `(1, 0)` to `B` and `(0, 1)` to `C`. (This puts the triangle ABC in a canonical position.)

Solving the 2x2 linear system

```
Dx = Ax + u (Bx - Ax) + v (Cx - Ax)
Dy = Ay + u (By - Ay) + v (Cy - Ay)
```

gives you the values of `(u, v)` corresponding to `D`.

Then,

```
if u < 0 => ABCD
else if v < 0 => BCAD
else => CABD
```

The resulting quadrilateral has the same orientation as the triangle `ABC`.

[image]

Comment: This one's much better and intelligent work. +1. :) please don't complain that I upvoted your answer. :P

Comment: This is an exact replica of my other answer, rephrased with canonical coordinates. The computation is identical (the 2x2 determinants when using Cramer are again the signed areas) and the discussion involves the same 2 comparisons/3 outcomes. It is indeed more readable.

Comment: But. Finally, it is more readable. Anyways, I'm removing my downvote from the other answer too as I've realized the same.

Comment: @shekharsuman: thank you. The "deep" reason to consider all these regions is to analyze the geometry of the solution space. You learn two things: 1) the boundaries of the regions are straight lines, so that collinearity (or area) tests are sufficient, and 2) there are 7 distinct regions, so that 3 test are enough to separate them. (It turns out that two are sufficient.)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity, I'm considering as a point `p_n` a point with coordinates `(x_n, y_n)`.

In order to connect 4 points you could follow these steps:

1. Get the point `p_1` with the smallest `x`.
2. Calculate the [slope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) of the 3 lines that go from `p_1` to each of the remaining points.
3. Connect `p_1` with the point `p_2` that composes the line with the greatest slope.
4. Connect `p_1` with the point `p_3` that composes the line with the smallest slope.
5. Connect the remaining point `p_4` with `p_2` and `p_3`.

Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, it only works in specific situations and thus is a bad answer.

The quadrilateral can be drawn by finding which pair of points amongst the 4 points is separated by the largest distance. Once this pair is found, the quadrileteral is drawn by linking the two remaining points with each point of the pair.

Comment: The input of (0,0), (2,1), (3,1), (10,0) contradicts this algorithm.

Comment: @shekharsuman: Shapiro is right. The algorithm links (1,0), (1,3), (2, 0) and (2,3), but (2, 0) crosses (1,3).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer has already proven to be wrong.

1. Calculate the center of the four points.
2. Enumerate the points in the counter-clock wise direction (or clockwise).
3. Link them together.

Comment: Step 2 requires angle calculations, which doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: This doesn't always work if the quadrilateral isn't convex. For example, three points on the corners of an equilateral triangle with the fourth point in the middle.

Comment: @PaulHankin yes you're right... let me think some more!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simplification of any of the [well-known algorithms for convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm). Jarvis would be easy. If the convex hull is a triangle, the quadrilateral is convex. Just insert the missing point anywhere in the edge list.  If the convex hull is a line (2 endpoints), just sort all the points on either x- or y-coordinate to get a degenerate quadrilateral. (If closer to horizontal (abs delta x > abs delta y), use x for sorting, else use y.)

Answer (score 0):

i think, you just need to join two points each time, we will get a line segment and check if the remaining other two points are on the same side of that line segments, if not thats not a line segment of required quadrilateral, if yes then proceed with different set of points (i.e on point can be one of the coordinate of this segment and other one would be form remaining two points) and check the same thing until u get 4 line segments

Answer (score 0):

Look around for convex hull algorithms. One of them consists of two steps: building an ordinary polygon on a given set of vertices (which may be concave), then removing 'concave vertices' so that the remaining polygon becomes convex.

The first step is a solution for your problem.

Of course it is kind of overkill. For 4 vertices just set them in a sequence (in any order) then verify if line segments joining points 1-2 and 3-4 intersect; if so, swap points 2 and 3; or possibly edges 2-3 and 1-4 intersect – then swap points 3 and 4. Done.

To verify if segment AB and CD intersect test if points A and B are on opposite sides of the line CD and points C and D are on opposite sides of line AB.

To identify the side of a line PQ where a point K lies, calculate the *Z*-part of the PQ×PK vector product: `(xq-xp)(yk-yp)-(yq-yp)(xk-xp)`. The expression is positive on one side of the line and negative on the other one (and zero on the line).

Answer (score 0):

One can solve this problem very easily with the help of a function that says whether two line segments intersect.

Given points A, B, C, D, there's only three different orders to join up the vertices: ABCD, ABDC and ACBD (vertex A either connects to vertex B or it doesn't. If it does, there's two ways to order C and D. If it doesn't then A connects to both C and D and each of those must connect to B).

An ordering of the four points produces a quadrilateral if none of the edges intersect (except at the corners). That gives this procedure for finding a working order:

```
If AB intersects with CD then return ACBD.
If AD intersects with BC then return ABDC.
Otherwise return ABCD.
```

The proof that this works is easy:

1. both ABCD and ABDC include the edges AB and CD, so if those pair of edges intersect, the good order must be ACBD.
2. both ABCD and ACBD include the edges AD and BC, so if those pair of edges intersect, the good order must be ABDC.
3. if neither AB/CD and AD/BC intersect, then the order ABCD produces a quadrilateral.

The code for determining if two line segments intersect can be found online if you can't figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial, non-mathematical way of doing it. I've tried it on several examples and could not prove it wrong. Please let me know if you do or know how to make it better:

1. Choose the two points that are on the right of the others, say point 1 and 2.
2. Link points 1-2 together, as well as points 3-4.
3. Each point must be linked to only two other points so there are only 2 possibilities: linking points 1-3 and 2-4, or points 1-4 and 2-3.
4. Check if each line intersects another.

That should do it.

Note: when choosing the first two points, here are some special cases:

1. Point 1 is on the right of all others, but points 2 and 3 are on the same x coordinate. Pick the point that's closest to point 1.
2. If three points 1,2 and 3 have the same x-coordinate, link the two that are closest to each other. If the points are evenly separated, pick one of the two possibilities.