# Processing 3.0: Check if Triangle has been clicked on

Tags: processing

For example if I had a triangle with these properties

```
triangle(100, 300, 200, 200, 300, 300);
```

or just think of it as

```
triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

How would you write an if statement to check if mousePressed() is within the triangle shape?

Comment: Have you tried google at all? Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-2d-triangle) and [this](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/) and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInterior.html) for a start. Please **try something** and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin pointed out, this is an already well documented question and answer.

For fun, there's a hacky workaround to avoid the math using [PShape](https://processing.org/reference/PShape.html).
There is an undocumented `contains()` function which checks is an x,y pair is inside all the points of a PShape. That's nice, since this applies for all sort of other shapes, not just triangles. It's a point in polygon test instead of a point in triangle test. There is a catch however. This function isn't documented because it's probably still experimental so there are gotchas:

- it works on `PATH` type only PShapes
- `PATH` type PShapes that aren't loaded (from an SVG file for example) don't render using the `shape()` function, so you have to manually loop through vertices and draw the shape

Here's an example:

```
PShape triangle;

void setup(){
  size(100,100,P2D);
  noStroke();

  //create the triangle as PATH type PShape 
  triangle = new PShape(PShape.PATH);
  //add it's vertices
  triangle.vertex(50,10);
  triangle.vertex(10,90);
  triangle.vertex(90,90);

}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  //check if point is inside triangle
  if(triangle.contains(mouseX,mouseY)){
    fill(127);
  }else{
    fill(0);
  }
  //render triangle accessing the vertices previously set
  beginShape(TRIANGLE);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < triangle.getVertexCount(); i++){
    PVector v = triangle.getVertex(i);
    vertex(v.x,v.y);
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

However, in practice you might find using the math approach simpler (since there are less workarounds to worry about).