# How to test a point is inside or outside of a Triangle?

Tags: java, data-structures, geometry

Create a Java Program to create a 2 dimensional virtual triangle and check if a point falls inside it. Console input/output functionality will be as follows:

INPUT: Ask user to enter X,Y integer coordinates for 1st vertex of triangle
INPUT: Ask user to enter X,Y integer coordinates for 2nd vertex of triangle
INPUT: Ask user to enter X,Y integer coordinates for 3rd vertex of triangle
INPUT: Ask user to enter X,Y integer coordinates for a test point
OUTPUT: Check and print if the point is inside or outside the triangle

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assignment to me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a point is in a 2D triangle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-in-a-2d-triangle)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's what I found from a quick search:](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/)

The gist is that you take the point (Point Z) that you're trying to figure out if it's inside or outside the triangle and draw a horizontal line from Point Z's x value to ∞. If this line (Line Z) intersects only and exactly one of the triangles sides, then we can conclude that Point Z is inside the triangle. In order to determine if it intersects the one of the sides, a good strategy would be to form `y=mx+b` equations from the sides. Given these equations, you can then determine how many sides Line Z intersects with. Note that if you find that Line Z intersects with two lines or more lines, check whether or not Point Z is one of the vertices of the triangle. If it is, then it's up to you if you want to consider that as inside or outside. If Point Z is not a vertex, then it is guaranteed to not be inside the triangle at all.