# Add rectangles to a trapezoid openCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image with two areas.  I want to add now rectangles with a fixed size randomly into area2. The coordinate origin of the image is in the top-left corner. I have the cordinates of the area2. This are P1, P2, P3(0, y_max) and P4(x_max, y_max). Does anybody knows how to check, if a rectangle lies in this area?
I can try to separate this area into 2 parts, a rectangle (rect_area) and a triangle (trangle_area). For the rect_area I can check with

`bool intersects = ((rect_area & rect_random).area() > 0);` if the random rect lies inside the area. For the triangle I have found some complicated stuff like here: [How to determine if a point is in a 2D triangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-in-a-2d-triangle)

Does anybody knows an easier way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the graph you draw represent the general case of the problem?

- P1.x == 0
- P2.x == 0
- q1.x == q2.x
- q2.y == q3.y

If the above conditions hold, then you can check

- if q1 is below the line of P1P2 (q1.y > (q1.x*(p2.y-p1.y)/x_max)+p1.y)
- q2 is abovep2 (q2.y < P2.y)

[image]

Comment: P2.x > 0. How can I check, if q1 is above or below Line P1P2?

Comment: you can check q1.y > (q1.x*(p2.y-p1.y)/x_max)+p1.x

Comment: I don´t see it right now. Can you explain the equation, please?

Comment: I made a typo, it should be q1.y > (q1.x*(p2.y-p1.y)/x_max)+p1.y

Comment: (p2.y-p1.y)/x_max  is the slope (dy/dx) of the line, p1.y is the offset. it is y coordinate of line at q.x is given by  q.x*(slope of line) + (offset of line)