# Evaluate the weights of a convex combination

Tags: math, convex-hull, convex, convex-polygon, scipy-spatial

I'm using the scipy.spatial.ConvexHull API for evaluating the convex hull of a set of points and it works well. Given the code below:

```
p1 = points[11]
hull = ConvexHull(points)
vertices = [points[i] for i in hull.vertices]
```

how can I evaluate the coefficients(weights) of the convex combination of `vertices` that equals to `p1`?

Thank you very much,
Moshe

Comment: if the number of points in `vertices` is higher than `d+1`, where `d` is the dimension, then the combination will **not** be unique.

Comment: A possibility is to search for a triplet of vertices A,B,C such that p1 is contained in triangle A,B,C; then solve the system of two linear equations described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049712/3080723 to find the coefficients using these three vertices.

Comment: @Stef, is there a simple way to check if a point is contained in a triangle, especially for N-dim points? Python implementation would be preferable?

Comment: @Stef, just realized that for 3-D and higher-D points, triangle containment would not be sufficient.

Comment: In dimension 2, yes, and the link I gave in my previous comment describes several ways of checking if a point is inside a triangle. In dimension `d`, don't search for a triplet of points; search for a (d+1)-tuple instead, and check whether the point is contained inside this shape.

Comment: Note that I also gave an answer below with a different approach, and that one is easily generalizable to any dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: if the number of vertices is higher than `d+1`, where `d` is the dimension, then the combination will **not** be unique. In the remainder of the answer I assume that `d=2` for simplicity.*

**Input:**

- vertices `v0 = (x0, y0), v1 = (x1, y1), ..., vn = (xn, yn)`;
- a point `p1 = (x,y)`;

**Output:**

- a combination `a0, a1, ..., an`;

**such that:**

- `x = a0 * x0 + a1 * x1 + ... + an * xn`;
- `y = a0 * y0 + a1 * y1 + ... + an * yn`;
- `1 = a0 + a1 + ... + an`;
- forall i, `ai >= 0`.

This is a system of three linear equations in the unknown `(a0, a1, ..., an)`, along with n+1 linear inequations. We can solve this system using [scipy's linear programming module scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)

**Example solution:**

```py
import random                      # generate points
import scipy.spatial as scispa     # ConvexHull
import scipy.optimize as sciopt    # linprog
from scipy.sparse import identity  # identity matrix

points = [(random.randrange(0,100), random.randrange(0,100)) for _ in range(20)]
p1 = points[11]
hull = scispa.ConvexHull(points)
vertices = [points[i] for i in hull.vertices]

c = [1 for _ in vertices]
A = [[x for x,y in vertices], [y for x,y in vertices], [1 for _ in vertices]]
b = [p1[0], p1[1], 1]
s = sciopt.linprog(c, A_eq = A, b_eq = b)

>>> s.x
array([0.13393774, 0.06470577, 0.07367599, 0.09523271, 0.18924727,
       0.26909487, 0.17410566])
>>> p1
(36, 57)
>>> [sum(a*xi for a,(xi,_) in zip(s.x, vertices)), sum(a*yi for a,(_,yi) in zip(s.x, vertices))]
[36.00000000719907, 57.00000000671608]
```

**Important note:** I began this answer by warning that if there are more than 3 vertices in the plane, or more than d+1 vertices in dimension d, then there will be more than 1 solution to our system of equations. The code above only returns one solution, meaning that an arbitrary choice was made. You have control over this arbitrary choice: `scipy.optimize.linprog` is an optimisation tool; here it is minimizing the dot-product of the vector `c` we gave as parameter, and the solution vector `s.x`. Here I set all coefficients of `c` to 1, meaning `linprog` will find a solution that minimizes the sum of coefficients in the solution; try supplying a different vector `c` and you'll get a different solution.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works for me demonstrating reasonable performance, at least for small datasets and low dimensionality. I'll test it later for bigger datasets of vectors of higher dimensions. Thank you again.

Comment: @Moshe Hi Moshe! 8 months later: did you test with bigger datasets of vectors of higher dimensions?