# How to check if a point in a triangle (or on it's edge)

Tags: c++, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to write an algorithm to determine if point is located inside a triangle or on it's edge in 3D coordinate space.
For example, I try to reach such results for different cases
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've figured out how to check if point P **inside** the triangle, I calculated normal vectors for triangles ABP, BCP, CAP and checked if they are similar.

Can someone explain how to check if a point is on the edge of a triangle (but not outside of a triangle)? You can provide formulas or code as you wish.

Comment: minor nit, triangle is 2d not 3d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-in-a-2d-triangle

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles

Comment: @pm100, I have a triangulated mesh in 3d space, so the triangles themselves have 3d coordinates

Comment: Can a point be 'in the triangle' while not being on the same plane as the triangle?

Comment: @Tyler, what do you mean?

Comment: I think @Tyler is asking if the point has to be on the triangle plane or if you are doing some projection into 2d and checking the projected point vs the projected triangle.

Comment: He's asking if the point can be above or below the triangle and still be true?

Comment: Side note, if you're looking for a formula you can turn into code, you might be better off asking at Mathematics.

Comment: The point lies on the same plane as the triangle. But I want to check if it is between two points or on the same line (like 4th picture) but outside the triangle

Comment: First pass: generate a bounding box of the triangle.  You can quickly check to see if the point is inside-or-outside the bounding box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a point is in a 2D triangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-in-a-2d-triangle)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34093754/10091872

Comment: A point lies on the edge if it is colinear with any two points of the triangle. Remember, this is CS, so there will be a small _epsilon_ you should account for. If the point computes as _in_ the triangle _and_ as reasonably colinear with AB, AC, or BC, then it is on the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Make vectors:

```
r = p - A (r.x = p.x - A.x, r.y = p.y - A.y, r.z = p.z - A.z)
s = B - A
q = C - A
```

Calculate normal to ABC plane:

```
n = s x q  (vector product)
```

Check if `p` lies in ABC plane using dot product:

```
dp = n.dot.r
```

If `dp` is zero (or has very small value like `1.0e-10` due to the floating point errors, then `p` is in the plane, and we can continue

Decompose vector `p` by base vectors `s` and `q`. At first check if z-component of normal (`n.z`) is non-zero. If so, use the next pair of equations (otherwise choose equations for x/z or y/z components):

```
px = a * sx + b * qx
py = a * sy + b * qy
```

Solve this system

```
a =  (sy * qx - sx * qy) / (py * qx - px * qy)  
b =  (px - a * sx) / qx
```

If resulting coefficients `a` and `b` fulfill limits:

```
a >= 0
b >= 0
a + b <= 1.0
```

then point `p` lies in triangle plane inside it.

Comment: Hi MBo. If you consider a rotation that brings the triangle in the plane XY, the resolution becomes crystal clear, most of it becoming a 2D discussion. And tolerancing (in terms of distances) becomes easy to deal with.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Here I use projection onto proper plane. It seems for me that rotation is a bit more complex. Concerning rotation approach - it is worth to transform vertices into (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0)  - affine matrix calulation should be simpler, final stage is elementary.

Comment: The projection on a plane is still 3D, and the rotation is simpler than you think. The affine transformation is tempting, but it does not preserve the Euclidean distance. But what matters most, the geometry is easier to think about.