# MATLAB - generating a 2d triangle aperture for diffraction

Tags: matlab, triangle

I have a logical square array such that a value of 1 signifies that light is allowed to pass through the array at those points, and a value of 0 means that light is blocked.

How do I create a triangular aperture shape in this array? I am genuinely stumped and have racked my brain quite a bit but cannot come up with a solution.

Comment: Please can you define more precisely which elements should be 1 or 0 to define your triangle? Which orientation should the triangle be? Which points should be the 3 corners and how should elements be treated if the edge of the triangle would intercept them partially in an analogous grid? Note that it's trivial to make a matrix with a triangle using [`triu`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) but I imagine that's not what you want

Answer (score 1):

Consider the logical array as the result of many evaluations of a function, with input `x` and `y`.  Then your job is to create the function that returns `true` for points inside the triangle, and `false` for points outside.

And what would that function be?  For that, see the many answers provided on this (unfortunately and inappropriately closed question): [How to determine if a point is in a 2D triangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-in-a-2d-triangle)

Or, since this is MATLAB, use the more general (and therefore less performant) `inpolygon`.  Express the triangle as a list of x coordinates and a list of y coordinates.

Then, test all your points by generating a grid of x and y over your logical matrix, and pass all those points to `inpolygon`.

The following is untested:

```
N = 256;  % size of logical array
x = linspace(-1, 1, N);  % let's define the coordinate space of your array as -1 to 1
y = linspace(-1, 1, N);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

tri_x = [-.75 0 .75];  % strange triangle
tri_y = [.25 .75 .25];

in_triangle = inpolygon(X, Y, tri_x, tri_y);
```

Comment: fwiw as OP wants a square array, you can just pass `x` as both inputs to `meshgrid` and avoid defining `y`, but this works for a more generic rectangular array