# Getting number of points in a 2D triangle

Tags: python, math, geometry

**The Story:**

- *Input:* 3 coordinates - the vertices of a triangle
- *Desired Output:* number of points with *integer coordinates* located inside a triangle, not including boundaries

My initial idea was to get the coordinates of the rectangle containing the triangle, iterate over the points inside it and use one of the ["Is this point inside a triangle?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300904/determine-whether-point-lies-inside-triangle) solutions to determine if a point is inside a triangle. What I have so far:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter


def is_inside_triangle(s, p1, p2, p3):
    as_x = s.x - p1.x
    as_y = s.y - p1.y

    s_ab = (p2.x - p1.x) * as_y - (p2.y - p1.y) * as_x > 0

    if ((p3.x - p1.x) * as_y - (p3.y - p1.y) * as_x > 0) == s_ab:
        return False

    if ((p3.x - p2.x) * (s.y - p2.y) - (p3.y - p2.y) * (s.x - p2.x) > 0) != s_ab:
        return False

    return True


def solution(vertices):
    Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x,y')
    vertices = [Point(x, y) for x, y in vertices]

    min_x = min(vertices, key=attrgetter('x')).x
    min_y = min(vertices, key=attrgetter('y')).y

    max_x = max(vertices, key=attrgetter('x')).x
    max_y = max(vertices, key=attrgetter('y')).y

    return sum(1
               for x in range(min_x + 1, max_x)
               for y in range(min_y + 1, max_y)
               if is_inside_triangle(Point(x, y), *vertices))
```

It works for the following inputs:

```
print(solution([(-1, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]))  # 1
print(solution([[3, 3], [4, 2], [10, 190]]))  # 96
```

This approach though proved to be very slow on large enough triangles, like:

```
print(solution([[91207, 89566], [-88690, -83026], [67100, 47194]]))
```

which works for hours.

**The Question:**

I think the main problem is that I am trying to check too many points that can be ruled out beforehand. What is the most *efficient* way to count the number of points in a triangle?

Comment: @Karin, I guess I have not searched good enough. Thanks for pointing out this is a duplicate!

Comment: For those who are interested in an efficient Python-specific solution, here is what I eventually switched to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39175060/771848.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "point" seems very inaccurate to me, the number of *points* is infinite in most cases. Do you mean number of "pixels"? Then why not use the equation for triangle area, e.g. `abs((xB*yA-xA*yB)+(xC*yB-xB*yC)+(xA*yC-xC*yA))/2`, measured in pixels?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccurate terminology (tried to make it a bit better by using "points with integer coordinates" instead of "points"). The equation takes into account the borders of the triangle, correct? If yes, would it be possible to adjust it to not include the borders? Thanks.